# Is it possible to use a nested delete in SPARQL queries?

Tags: sparql, blank-nodes

I would like to use a query to deduplicate resources using a unique id. An insert/delete - query doesn't work, because less nodes have to be created than are deleted. Is it possible to use something similar to this?

```
insert {
    ?new a mails:Account.
    ?new mails:hasID ?id.
    ?new rdfs:label ?label
  }
where {
    {
        select distinct ?id ?label where {
            ?account a mails:Account.
            ?account mails:hasID ?id.
            ?account rdfs:label ?label
        }
    }
    bind(bnode() as ?new)
    {
        delete where {
            ?account mails:hasID ?id
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just "because less nodes have to be created than are deleted" doesn't necessarily mean that you can't use a normal insert/delete. RDF is a set-based representation; if you insert the same triple multiple times, it's the same as inserting it once.  If you want to normalize a bunch of triples, you can create the same blank node for query results by using **bnode** with an argument: (emphasis added):

> The [BNODE](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-bnode) function constructs a blank node that is distinct from all
>   blank nodes in the dataset being queried and distinct from all blank
>   nodes created by calls to this constructor for other query solutions.
>   If the no argument form is used, every call results in a distinct
>   blank node. **If the form with a simple literal is used, every call
>   results in distinct blank nodes for different simple literals, and the
>   same blank node for calls with the same simple literal within
>   expressions for one solution mapping.**

This means that you can do:

```sql
insert {
  ?new a mails:Account.
  ?new mails:hasID ?id.
  ?new rdfs:label ?label
}
delete {
  ?account mails:hasId ?id
}
where {
  ?account a mails:Account.
  ?account mails:hasID ?id.
  ?account rdfs:label ?label

  #-- One new bnode is created for each *distinct*
  #-- ?id value.  If two accounts have the same 
  #-- ?id value, then they will get the same bnode().
  bind (bnode(str(?id)) as ?new)
}
```

If you're trying to merge *all* accounts into one, even if they have different IDs, then you could just pass a constant value into the **bnode** function, e.g.,

```
bind (bnode("") as ?new)
```

Comment: Great solution. Thanks!